# Get all the data of a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jstl

I am using JSTL in JSP. My JSP code is

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
  <c:forEach var="batchJob" items="${allBatchJobs}">
    <form action="dummy.jsp">
      <div class="square img-fluid img-thumbnail">
        <span class="process-name">${batchJob.batchName}</span>
      </div>
  </c:forEach>
</div>
```

I want to get all the data of the span process-name in JS. For this I am using this code in script.

```
var batchJobNames = $('.process-name').html();
```

This is returning the first name as expected, but I want all the names in an array.

Comment: The dupe is using LI but the method is the same `var batchJobNames =  $('.process-name').map(function(){
  return $(this).text();
}).get().join(',');`

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks. I want all the data to be stored in an array. do you have something in mind for this

Comment: remove the `.join(',')` from my example

Comment: Also there is nothing JSTL/JSP about this question. Next time post the rendered HTML in a [mcve] using the snippet editor

Comment: that worked. Thank you so much for your time